# I can't delete dynamically allocated 2D array after it gets value from txt file

Tags: c++, arrays

I create a dynamically allocated 2D array and use it to store grey value from txt file. I am sure it gets the right value, but a error message pup up and said "Heap corruption detected, CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer".

But if I delete the code in "//********" part, then no warning appears. Please help me with it, thank you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
typedef unsigned char byte;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const char *sLoadPath = "D:\\Matlab Work\\pout.txt";
    FILE *file_handle;
    const int iImgH = 291, iImgW = 240;

    byte **ppu8Image = new byte *[iImgH];
    ppu8Image[0] = new byte [iImgH*iImgW];
    for (int i = 1; i < iImgH; i++)
    {
        ppu8Image[i] = ppu8Image[i - 1] + iImgW;
    }
    //******************************
    file_handle = fopen(sLoadPath, "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < iImgH*iImgW; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file_handle, "%d", &ppu8Image[i / iImgW][i % iImgW]);
    }
    fclose(file_handle);
    //******************************
    delete[] * ppu8Image;
    delete[] ppu8Image;
    ppu8Image = NULL;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is stdafx.h header file?

Comment: 'new' and 'delete' are C++, not C.  Suggest removing the 'c' tag

Comment: stdafx.h if I remember correctly is a header auto generated when you create a certain template of visual studio project.

Comment: Since this is C++, the code should have overloaded 'cin' rather than using fscanf().   However, the returned value from fscanf() should always be checked (in this case == 1) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding these two lines: 'byte **ppu8Image = new byte *[iImgH];
    ppu8Image[0] = new byte [iImgH*iImgW];'  the first line allocates an array of pointers to byte   The second line allocates a very large array and places that pointer into the first entry in the array of pointers that was allocated in the first line.   I.E. only the first entry in the array of pointers to byte was set.   The typical method is 1) allocate an array of pointers to byte, one pointer per row  2) for each entry in the first allocation, allocate an array for a single row.

Comment: @user3629249: False. The cycle that immediately follows the allocation is there specifically to initialize the remaining pointers in the first array. In fact, this is the correct way to allocate things: the row memory is allocated in one large block, instead of allocating each row independently. Independent row allocation should be reserved for sparse arrays. This one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what is stated in other answers, your memory allocation is performed correctly.

One obvious error though is that you are reading data using `%d` format specifier in `fscanf`. Format `%d` requires an argument of type `int *` and saves the data into an `int` object in memory. But you are supplying your `fscanf` with an argument of type `byte *`, which is `unsigned char *`. `unsigned char` is smaller than `int`, which means that `fscanf` overrides (destroys) some memory you don't own. This damage is exactly what is detected later as heap corruption.

If you want to `fscanf` individual `unsigned char` values from file, use `%c` format specifier. But there's no way to say how to properly read your file without knowing its format.

Comment: Sorry guys, the programming enviroment is Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

given the desired process is to allocate an array of pointers to byte

Then allocate bytes for each row

Then this code block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iImgH*iImgW; i++)
{
    fscanf(file_handle, "%d", &ppu8Image[i / iImgW][i % iImgW]);
}
```

should actually be a nested pair of 'for' loops something like:

```
for( int i = 0; i < iImgH; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < iImgW; j++)
    {
         fscanf...  ppu8Image[i][j] )
    }
}
```

However, the main problem is that no allocation was made for any for the array of pointers to byte, except the first

Comment: The allocation is made properly. The cycle that immediately follows the allocation is there specifically to initialize the remaining pointers in the first array.

Comment: As for the nested pair of loops... It does indeed produce a more readable code, but the OP's original looping approach is also perfectly correct (albeit probably less efficient). In fact, given the way the array is allocated, the OP could've simply read `ppu8Image[0][j]` in one pass for `j` from `0` to `iImgH*iImgW - 1`. That would be the most efficient approach.